# Oracle JDBC exception, in webapp, in Tomcat deployment: No suitable driver at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver

Tags: eclipse, java-8, ojdbc, jersey-1.0, tomcat9

I am unit-testing my jersey web-service through jersey client using eclipse Oxygen.3a, Tomcat 9,  JDK 1.8, and ojbc14.jar in my WEB-INF/lib of my web-app in eclipse. I do not have any ojdbc.jar's in my Tomcat/lib dir. So there is single copy of my ojdbc jar file, i.e. ojdbc14.jar. My JDBC URL is `jdbc:oracle:thin:@mcname.com:1521:orcl1`.

My request is failing due to the following error:

> Exception when obtaining connection
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
>       at 
>   :

Code:

```
DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old Java 1.4/1.5 OJDBC driver with JDK 1.8. You should update the JAR to `ojdbc8.jar` as per [What are the Oracle JDBC releases versus JDK versions?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1). Running an outdated OJDBC driver is not a good idea, if you get `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` it means that driver registration might have failed.

Do note that if your `url` variable is `jdbc:oracle:thin:@mcname.com:1521:orcl1` than the code becomes

```
DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:oracle:thin:@jdbc:oracle:thin:@mcname.com:1521:orcl1);
```

and the URL duplicates `jdbc:oracle:thin:@`. Do check that you are creating the URL correctly.

Comment: ok, now I am using Java 7, as there were some other dependencies, with asm.jar. So configuration now, is Jersey 1.10, Tomcat 9, JDK 1.7, ojdbc7.jar.  Still getting same exception as above:                                                               
 **java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)**                                                                    
`My code flow is:  
`DriverManager.getDriver(url);
}catch (SQLException e) {
String urlStr="jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + url;
DriverManager.getDriver(urlStr);`

Comment: So, I am testing for both the scenarios    `1)DriverManager.getDriver("mcname.com:1521:orcl1")                                                                 
                                                                                                           
 2)If above code throws exception, then try below code: DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:oracle:thin:@mcname.com:1521:orcl1")`

Comment: @SoumaliChatterjee `jdbc:oracle:thin:@mcname.com:1521:orcl1` is the right URL. You need to debug `Driver.getDriver(String)` method to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I tried DriverManager.getDrivers(), in order to get the list of JDBC drivers which are loaded, it prints nothing. This means no drivers have got loaded